# Sorting by data in another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been stuck with an engineering problem thats Python/Pandas related. I'd appreciate any help given.
I've simplified the numbers so I can better explain myself.
I have something similar to the following:

|  | positioning(x-axis) | Calculated difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.25 | 0.05 |
| 2 | 0.75 | 0.06 |
| 3 | 1.25 | 0.02 |
| 4 | 0.25 | 0.05 |
| 5 | 0.75 | 0.05 |
| 6 | 1.25 | 0.02 |
| 7 | 0.25 | 0.09 |
| 8 | 0.75 | 0.01 |
| 9 | 1.25 | 0.02 |
| 10 | 0.25 | 0.05 |

What I need to do is re-organise the calculated difference based on the x-axis positioning.
So it looks something like this:

| (0.25) | (0.75) | (1.25) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.05 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0.06 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0.02 |
| 0.5 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0.5 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0.02 |
| 0.09 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0.01 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0.02 |
| 0.05 | 0 | 0 |

As you can see, I need to organize everything based on the x-positioning.
What is the best approach to this problem? Keep in mind I have 2000+ rows and the x positioning is dynamic but I'm currently working till up to 50(so a lot of columns).

I hope I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
In [10]: pd.get_dummies(df['positioning(x-axis)']).mul(df['Calculated difference'],axis=0)
Out[10]: 
    0.25  0.75  1.25
1   0.05  0.00  0.00
2   0.00  0.06  0.00
3   0.00  0.00  0.02
4   0.05  0.00  0.00
5   0.00  0.05  0.00
6   0.00  0.00  0.02
7   0.09  0.00  0.00
8   0.00  0.01  0.00
9   0.00  0.00  0.02
10  0.05  0.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do `pivot`

```
df.pivot(columns='positioning(x-axis)',values='Calculated difference').fillna(0)
Out[363]: 
Calculated  0.25  0.75  1.25
0           0.05  0.00  0.00
1           0.00  0.06  0.00
2           0.00  0.00  0.02
3           0.05  0.00  0.00
4           0.00  0.05  0.00
5           0.00  0.00  0.02
6           0.09  0.00  0.00
7           0.00  0.01  0.00
8           0.00  0.00  0.02
9           0.05  0.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `factorize`

```
i, p = pd.factorize(df['positioning(x-axis)'])
d = df['Calculated difference'].to_numpy()

a = np.zeros_like(d, shape=(len(df), len(p)))
a[np.arange(len(df)), i] = d

pd.DataFrame(a, df.index, p)

   0.25  0.75  1.25
0  0.05  0.00  0.00
1  0.00  0.06  0.00
2  0.00  0.00  0.02
3  0.05  0.00  0.00
4  0.00  0.05  0.00
5  0.00  0.00  0.02
6  0.09  0.00  0.00
7  0.00  0.01  0.00
8  0.00  0.00  0.02
9  0.05  0.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use pandas' `pivot` and then to reset the index.
Given a data frame like this:

```
     positioning(x-axis)  Calculated difference
0                   0.0                   0.61
1                   0.0                   0.96
2                   0.0                   0.56
3                   0.0                   0.91
4                   0.0                   0.57
5                   0.0                   0.67
6                   0.1                   0.71
7                   0.1                   0.71
8                   0.1                   0.95
9                   0.1                   0.89
10                  0.1                   0.61

df.pivot(columns='positioning(x-axis)', values='Calculated difference').reset_index().drop(columns=['index']).fillna(0)

positioning(x-axis)   0.0   0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.7   0.8   0.9   1.0
0                    0.61  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
1                    0.96  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
2                    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.22  0.00  0.00
3                    0.00  0.66  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
4                    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.13  0.00  0.00
5                    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
6                    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.91  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
7                    0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.85
8                    0.00  0.00  0.37  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
9                    0.00  0.91  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
```